# Use pm2 start a node app, that node app forks a child process, when the child process is down, Will pm2 restart the node app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process, pm2

Here is my problem that I have met.

There are three files in my node project named `app.js`, `app-8080.js`, `app-8090.js`.

The three files are almost the same except the port.

In `app.js`

```
server.listen(config.port0, () => {
    console.log(utilL.format('app is listening at http://%s:%s', config.host, config.port0));
});
```

In `app-8080.js`

```
// the above is the same as app.js
server.listen(config.port1, () => {
    console.log(utilL.format('app is listening at http://%s:%s', config.host, config.port1));
});
```

In `app-8090.js`

```
// the above is the same as app.js
server.listen(config.port2, () => {
    console.log(utilL.format('app is listening at http://%s:%s', config.host, config.port2));
});
```

When I update `app.js`, I have to do the same work three times.

Now I want to change as below.

In `app.js`

```
let port = (/^\d+$/.test(process.argv[2])) ? process.argv[2] : config.port0;
server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(utilL.format('app is listening at http://%s:%s', config.host, port));
});
```

In `app-8080.js`

```
const childProcess = require('child_process');
const config = require('./config/config');
let port = config.port1;
childProcess.fork('./app.js', [port]);
```

Is that OK? And I use PM2 to start `app-8080.js`

command as below:

```sh
$ pm2 start app-8080.js
```

When it occurs errors in `app.js`, will the pm2 restart this process?

And is there any other problem? Or what is the better solution?

I'll be very pleasure with your answer!

Comment: I guess that there is no support for a child process. Check this link (https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/1869)

Comment: I read this issue. And I write a little demo to test if pm2 restart when child_process is down. My pm2's version is `3.2.9`. And the result is pm2 restart the process that forks another process.